# Microsoft Test Management - How to determine which test to run on which machine in predefined lab environment

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I was able to setup a virtual lab environment including three virtual machines. When creating test cases with linked coded ui tests i still can not find out on how i would configure which test to run on which machine and also in which order to run them. So far the test only gets executed on one machine. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because default configuration, the minimum size of the buckets is 10 tests by default and this can be changed on a per controller basis by modifying the QTController.exe.config file in "%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\" and setting the “MinimumTestsPerAgent” application key. This file will be present in the controller machine

You can add the following line

```
<add key="MinimumTestsPerAgent" value="1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick help! Is there also a way of telling which tests should be executed on which machine in the environment and also the execution order?

Comment: Execution order can be altered by using an ordered test.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can control Run a Test on specific machine.

goto lab centre  - > Controllers and select your Test controller

All the test agent for this controller will be listed in Order.
note down this order and goto MTM Plan and Test suite where your tests are.
here click on Order Tests. now let say you want to Run a Test called Sanity test on a Test agent which is on no 2 in the list in Lab centre then you need to order this test as No 2
and in same way you can order them here and it will Run